# What "Operation cannot be fulfilled on nodes" means

Tags: kubernetes

I deploy a v1.11 kube-cluster by kubeadm with one master and three node.

My kube-controller pods frequently log:

> E1012 08:17:42.897796 node_lifecycle_controller.go:889] Error
>   updating node izwz95wx4ufpnolro1iekmz: Operation cannot be fulfilled on
>   nodes "izwz95wx4ufpnolro1iekmz": the object has been modified; please
>   apply your changes to the latest version and try again

"izwz95wx4ufpnolro1iekmz" node will be NotReady periodically and kubectl describe node provide nothing useful information but just NotReady status.

How to debug my cluster and find out the root cause?

Comment: Have you observed the same issue on the other worker nodes? Do you have all `kube-system` runtime components up and running on a master node? General troubleshooting actions with the cluster described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/).

Comment: @mk_sta Somtimes this problem turns to the other woker nodes after rebooting the node that is in trouble. So it seems that this problem will occur at all woker nodes and i dont know what leads to it. All components that should be at master node have been up. By the way I have a woker node which version is 1.13 and the others are 1.11 including master one.

Comment: Have you considered to apply the same Kubernetes version as on the master node and re-join this worker node to the cluster ?

Comment: @mk_sta I have tried deleting the node, but it does not work.

Comment: Check `kubelet` logs on the affected node and also take a loot at API server logs for any relevant events.

Answer (score -1):

Remove these lines from the file:

```
creationTimestamp:   
  resourceVersion:  
  selfLink:   
  uid:
```

Then try to apply again.

Comment: Could you try to elaborate more? Delete those lines from which K8s object?